# Centering items with Bootstrap and CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a very newbie problem with my page: I cannot center my div-image in the header and I can't vertical-center the content. This is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the position I want it to be is `POS`. I tried `margin:auto`, using flex and I can't seem to fix it! I also tried with bootstrap, but I'm very confused.

This is the "code":

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo-holder"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="container align-middle">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img src="{{ object.image.url }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
```

*CSS:*

```
body{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.container img{
    border: 1.5px solid rgb(138, 137, 137);
    width: 400px;
}
header{
    height: 10em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
header .logo-holder{
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../img/main-logo.png) no-repeat center center;
    width: 104px; height: 85px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 10%;
    }

.container h1{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #353738; 
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 30px; 
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

I know this should be easy for you, but don't to frontend. I tried to investigate, but what it works in a code snipped online won't seem to work in my code somehow. Do you have any idea on how to center the logo and how to vertical-align the product div (the div that contains the image and the title)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed some things in your CSS and it works for me.

I removed the Flex elements in the `header`
and gave the `logo-header` a `display:block;` and `margin:auto auto;`. Also removed the absolute positioning of the `logo-header`.

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.container img{
    border: 1.5px solid rgb(138, 137, 137);
    width: 400px;
}
header{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height: 10em;
}
header .logo-holder{
    display:block;
    margin:auto auto;
    background: url('../img/main-logo.png') no-repeat center center;
    width: 104px; height: 85px;
    }

.container h1{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #353738; 
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 30px; 
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea on how to vertical-align the product container?

Comment: @MartínSchere : You could make the .container a Flex and the height of it 100%. But I don't know your whole page. It might need some adjustment.

`.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
}`